# Auto-imported components are marked as custom html tags in PhpStorm/WebStorm

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, phpstorm, nuxtjs3, auto-import

Using NuxtJS 3 the recognition of auto-imported components like:

```
../foo/bar.vue -> <FooBar />
```

does not work, although there's a mapping in `.nuxt/components.d.ts`, which is referenced in `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  // https://v3.nuxtjs.org/concepts/typescript
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

The content of `./.nuxt/tsconfig.json`:

```json
// Generated by nuxi
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "..",
    "paths": {
      "~~": [
        "."
      ],
      "~~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@@": [
        "."
      ],
      "@@/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "~": [
        "."
      ],
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@": [
        "."
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "assets": [
        "assets"
      ],
      "assets/*": [
        "assets/*"
      ],
      "public": [
        "public"
      ],
      "public/*": [
        "public/*"
      ],
      "#app": [
        "node_modules/nuxt/dist/app"
      ],
      "#app/*": [
        "node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/*"
      ],
      "vue-demi": [
        "node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/compat/vue-demi"
      ],
      "@intlify/shared": [
        "node_modules/@intlify/shared/dist/shared.esm-bundler"
      ],
      "@intlify/core-base": [
        "node_modules/@intlify/core-base/dist/core-base.esm-bundler"
      ],
      "@intlify/devtools-if": [
        "node_modules/@intlify/devtools-if/dist/devtools-if.esm-bundler"
      ],
      "vue-i18n": [
        "node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.esm-bundler"
      ],
      "#auth/runtime": [
        "node_modules/@nuxtjs-alt/auth/dist/runtime"
      ],
      "#auth/runtime/*": [
        "node_modules/@nuxtjs-alt/auth/dist/runtime/*"
      ],
      "#head": [
        "node_modules/nuxt/dist/head/runtime"
      ],
      "#head/*": [
        "node_modules/nuxt/dist/head/runtime/*"
      ],
      "#components": [
        ".nuxt/components"
      ],
      "#imports": [
        ".nuxt/imports"
      ],
      "#build": [
        ".nuxt"
      ],
      "#build/*": [
        ".nuxt/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./nuxt.d.ts",
    "../**/*"
  ]
}
```

And `nuxt.d.ts`

```
// Generated by nuxi
/// <reference types="@intlify/nuxt3" />
/// <reference types="@nuxtjs-alt/google-fonts" />
/// <reference types="@nuxtjs-alt/auth" />
/// <reference types="@nuxtjs-alt/axios" />
/// <reference types="@nuxtjs-alt/pinia" />
/// <reference types="@nuxt/content" />
/// <reference types="@nuxtjs/tailwindcss" />
/// <reference types="@nuxt/telemetry" />
/// <reference types="nuxt" />
/// <reference path="types/plugins.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="types/vue-shim.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="types/schema.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="types/content.d.ts" />
/// <reference types="vue-router" />
/// <reference path="types/middleware.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="types/layouts.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="components.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="types/auto-imports.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="imports.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="types/nitro.d.ts" />

export {}
```

This is an example:

[image: error message]

Does anybody have the same issue? Is there something wrong in my config?

Answer (score 1):

Create file jsconfig.json in root directory with content of tsconfig.json

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CphDG.png)

Comment: not sure how adding the `jsconfig.json` can help here

Comment: added screenshot in the post

Comment: `jsconfig.json` won;t help with global components recognition

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[WEB-56566](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-56566/Nuxt-3-global-components-are-unresolved-whereas-they-are-exposed-in-componentsdts) is fixed in upcoming 2022.3 update